# Lazy Loading Spring Beans as part of Integration Test

Tags: java, spring

The Test class of my application is extending "AbstractSingleSpringContextTests".

We are loading all the Spring config files by overriding the "getConfigLocations" method.

All Spring files that I am loading are bundled inside JAR files (which are provided by other teams).

Hence the startup time for the integration tests is quite high. I am unable to set the default lazy load parameter to false since the spring config files are in JAR files.

1. Is there way to programmatically set lazy load to true while running
   the tests?
2. Is there a way to programmatically disallow certain beans defined in application-context.xml from loading?

Comment: What version of spring are you using?  You may be able to use the new environment configurations

Comment: Hi ,I am using spring 2.0. How can set it using env config?

Comment: you cannot it is a new feature in 3.1. I am not sure but you may be able to do jmx.

Comment: Not sure how much this helps, but you could turn off certain beans by defining beans with the same id in the context ahead of the ones you want to disable.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your suggestions.

I have able to lazily load by following the steps specified in this link - http://batmat.net/blog/post/2008/01/13/How-to-load-a-XML-Spring-context-lazily-by-default

Comment: Error 404! This link is not available anymore. Can you post the sollution please?

Comment: Here you can find the page linked above:
https://web.archive.org/web/20131220212736/http://batmat.net/blog/post/2008/01/13/How-to-load-a-XML-Spring-context-lazily-by-default

Comment: Thanks @GreenTurtle